# Transform words from file to array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, file

I have created a Vue application and currently have the following problem:

I have a given file with different words. 
I can customize the file format as I wish, however `Markdown` or a `text file` would be preferable. 
The file is located right next to the `App.vue` file --> in `.src`.

For example, this file contains the following content:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
```

Now I want to put these 4 words into an array. 
And my code in the `App.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
    ...
</template
<script>
    import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
    import someStuff from './components/SomeStuff'
    ...

    // here I want to in put the words
    const words= [];
    // here a random word is selected from this array
    // this works so far when I manually enter words to my array
    const randomWord = () => words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    export default {
        components: { SomeStuff },
        setup() { ...
```

And this is what I've tried so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var array = fs.readFileSync('./src/MyDataSet.txt').toString().split("\n");
for(i in words) {
    console.log(words[i]);
}
```

Only I don't know how to include this JS snippet in my Vue component. 
`require()` is not defined and I think I can't just put this code in there. 
I don't want to have any libraries, plugins or further dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the problem as follows. Of course, this is not the best or most optimal solution but it seems to work and cover the upper case.

I have written a new function, created a new file accordingly and imported it so that I can call the function locally.

The solution now looks like this:

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    import SomeStuff from "./components/SomeStuff";
    import generateWords from "./Dataset";

    const words = generateWords();
    const randomWort = () => words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    ...
</script>
```

And thats the new `Dataset.js` file:

```
export default function generateWords() {
    return [
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
        "Test3",
        "Test4"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a method in the script tag

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      wordArray: [],
    };
  },
  props: {},
  methods: {
        readWords() {
         var fs = require('fs');
         var array = fs.readFileSync('./src/MyDataSet.txt').toString().split("\n");
        
         this.wordArray.push(array)
      }
<script>
```

Then you call your function anywhere in the code and it fills "wordArray" so you can use it any way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then how does it work if I have my array of words defined outside my `export defaults`? I have included methods in the defaults that call `randomWord` and `words` among others.

Answer (score 0):

`fs` module is useful only on the server-side.
You can use `marked` or similar libraries.

Please refer to this link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked